# How to initialise custom vector type with a standard vector

Tags: c++, constructor, containers, std

I have created a sample container which internally stores in a std::vector.  I want to be able to initialise the container with a std::vector.  So I created constructors that take a std::initializer_list and also taking a begin and end.

But I can't seem to initialise like this:

```
const std::vector< uint8_t > vec1 { 1,2,3,4,5 };
UsingVectorExample ex{ vec1.begin(), vec1.end() };  // compilation errors on this line
```

What is the problem here?  and how can I fix?

The code is here:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

class UsingVectorExample
{
public:
    class iterator : public std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator
    {
    public:
        explicit iterator(typename std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator c)
            : std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator(c)
        {}
    };

    class const_iterator : public std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator
    {
    public:
        explicit const_iterator(typename std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator c)
            : std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator(c)
        {}
    };

    explicit UsingVectorExample(std::initializer_list<uint8_t> list)
        : m_vector(list.size())
    {
        m_vector.assign(list);
    }

    UsingVectorExample(iterator begin, iterator end)
        : m_vector(begin, end)
    {}

    UsingVectorExample(const_iterator begin, const_iterator end)
        : m_vector(begin, end)
    {}

    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(m_vector.begin());
    }

    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator(m_vector.end());
    }

    const_iterator begin() const
    {
        return const_iterator(m_vector.begin());
    }

    const_iterator end() const
    {
        return const_iterator(m_vector.end());
    }

    void push_back(const uint8_t& val)
    {
        m_vector.push_back(val);
    }

private:
    std::vector<uint8_t>  m_vector;
};


int main() {

    const std::vector< uint8_t > vec1 { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    UsingVectorExample ex{ vec1.begin(), vec1.end() };  // compilation errors on this line
}
```

Comment: You could have a constructor for `UsingVectorExample(std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator begin, std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator end)` parameters.

Comment: If you look at e.g. [this `std::vector` constructor reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) you will see that its own iterator constructor overload uses *templates*. That's really how all containers and functions in the standard library handles iterators.

Comment: Your own iterator cannot be constructed **implicitly** from `std::vector::iterator`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that your iterator constrcutors are `explicit`.  That means `vec1.begin()` can't be converted to a `UsingVectorExample::const_iterator` without you doing it explicitly like

```
UsingVectorExample ex{ UsingVectorExample::const_iterator{vec1.begin()}, 
                       UsingVectorExample::const_iterator{vec1.end()} };
```

To not have to do that, just remove the `explicit`.  You can see that working in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c54f912a6a13c6e)